# Why does my regular expression work in PHP but not JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex created by myself that I am currently running in PHP. Although when I merge it over to JavaScript, it refuses to work. I have also tried it in Python and it works perfectly fine.

Regex:

```
@[[](.[^]]+)[]][()](\d+)[)]
```

[Testing in PHP, and working](https://regex101.com/r/dE8tZ4/1#pcre)

[Testing in JavaScript, and not working](https://regex101.com/r/dE8tZ4/1#javascript)

Comment: have a look at the explanation - see how it differs, regex's are slightly different in different languages - make adjustments as required

Comment: Are you sure that you want to match something like: `@[]User Name])1234)`. It seems like an odd rule for any practical purpose.

Comment: @eBusiness - It's actually trying to match something along the lines of `@[User Name](1234)`. It is for a tagging system I have created so that I can convert that into a link to a users profile based on their ID by displaying their username.

Comment: @Fizzix I kind of figured that, it is just that the `.` and the second `)` doesn't really make any sense in that context.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't automatically escape your `]`.

This will help you get a visual idea:

### PCRE:

[image: PCRE]

### JS:

[image: JS]

### Python:

[image: Python]

So to fix this, you need to escape the brackets

```
@[[](.[^\]]+)[\]][()](\d+)[)]
//      ^     ^
```

The best way to write this regex is to minimize the use of character classes:

```
@\[(.[^\]]+)\][()](\d+)\)
```

That's why it's good practice to escape this stuff instead of relying on quirks of the flavor.

I generated these images through [regex101](https://regex101.com).

Comment: Ohhhh, makes much more sense now. Thanks vihan, appreciate it.

Comment: Is `[\]]` different from just `\]`?

Comment: @immibis No. This regex is probably better written as `@\[(.[^\]]+)\][()](\d+)\)`.

Comment: Thanks @Blackhole, looks a lot better. I'll run with that instead.